# multiple Form submission with authentication

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, ldap

I have scriptA and siteB that I submit my form to. Script B is a separate script that isn't mine so I cant change any of its settings..However, ScriptA is mine so I can post that script below. Given a login screen, a user puts in their login credentials then clicks login. After this, the form POSTS to scriptB which is in the action attribute of the form, then the form using JQUERY POSTS to scriptA. scriptB I dont care about, I just need to POST the form to it and thats that. ScriptA that is POSTED to takes the credentials POSTED to it and does an LDAP bind to see if the credentials match to the ones in DB, if they match, user is redirected to www.examplesite.com, if the given credentials are false then user is sent back to login screen saying invalid username and password.

ScriptB redirects on submission which I dont want, I dont even care what scriptB does, I just have to POST the credentials to it. I care about scriptA, once scriptA gets the proper credentials it should redirect the user. I cant make changes to scriptB so I have to somehow ignore its redirect.

What happens currently:
1) At login screen user hits submit after entering credentials
2) ScriptB is POSTED to through the action atribute, ScriptA is POSTED to through JQUERY
3) ScriptB redirects the user to www.examplesite.com

What **should** happen:
1) At login screen user hits submit after entering credentials
2) ScriptB is POSTED to through the action atribute, ScriptA is POSTED to through JQUERY
3) If scriptA finds the credentials wrong, it should redirect back to login screen with message invalid login.
4) once the user enters correct credentials at login screen user and scriptA approves these credentials, redirect user to www.example2site.com

Below is my scriptA, if I POST to it without scriptB then scriptA works just as intended but here I am trying to merge these 2 together.

scriptA is basically a website login authentication and it authenticates through LDAP bind.

Working login screen code that submits to both the scripts:

```
    <form action="http://servicedesk.site.com/j_security_check" method=post id="form" name="Auth" class="appnitro">
        <div class="form_description">
            <h2>Login</h2>

        </div>


            <ul >

                    <li id="li_1" >
        <label class="description" for="element_1">Username </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_1" name="j_username" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/>
        </div>
        </li>       <li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="element_2">Password </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_2" name="j_password" class="element text medium" type="password" maxlength="255" value=""/>
        </div>
        </li>

                    <li class="buttons">


                <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" />
        </li>
            </ul>

    </form>
```

JQUERY CODE:

```
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready( function(){

  $('#form').submit(function(){

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      async: true,
      url: "https://noc.sde.site.com/okhawaja/Login/formLanding/authenticate.php",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data, status, xhr){

      },
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        alert(status + ": " + err);
      }
    });

  });



});


        </script>
```

ScriptA:

```
<?php
session_start();

if( isset($_POST['j_username']) && isset($_POST['j_password']) )
{
    //LDAP stuff here.
    $username = trim($_POST['j_username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['j_password']);

    echo("Authenticating...");
    $ds = ldap_connect('ldap://ldap:port');

        ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

    //Can't connect to LDAP.
    if( !ds )
    {

$_SESSION['rdr']="Invalid Login. Try Again.";


        header( "Location: https://noc.sde.site.com/okhawaja/Login/formLanding/login.php" );


        exit;
    }

    //Connection made -- bind anonymously and get dn for username.
    $bind = @ldap_bind($ds);

    //Check to make sure we're bound.
    if( !bind )
    {
$_SESSION['rdr']="Invalid Login. Try Again.";



       header( "Location: https://noc.sde.site.com/okhawaja/Login/formLanding/login.php" );

        exit;
    }

    $search = ldap_search($ds, "ou=People,DC=sde,DC=site,DC=com", "uid=$username");

    //Make sure only ONE result was returned -- if not, they might've thrown a * into the username.  Bad user!
    if( ldap_count_entries($ds,$search) != 1 )
    {


$_SESSION['rdr']="Invalid Login. Try Again.";



        header( "Location: https://noc.sde.site.com/okhawaja/Login/formLanding/login.php" );

        redirect(_WEBROOT_ . "/try1b.php");

        exit;
    }

    $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $search);

    //Now, try to rebind with their full dn and password.
    $bind = @ldap_bind($ds, $info[0][dn], $password);
    if( !$bind || !isset($bind))
    {


$_SESSION['rdr']="Invalid Login. Try Again.";



header( "Location: https://noc.sde.site.com/okhawaja/Login/formLanding/login.php" );

        redirect(_WEBROOT_ . "/try1b.php");

        exit;
    }

    //Now verify the previous search using their credentials.
    $search = ldap_search($ds, "ou=People,DC=sde,DC=rogersdigitalmedia,DC=com", "uid=$username");

    $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $search);
    if( $username == $info[0][uid][0] )
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['fullname'] = $info[0][cn][0]; 
        $_SESSION['email'] = $info[0][mail][0];
        $_SESSION['phone'] = $info[0][telephonenumber][0];
header( "Location: https://noc.sde.site.com/okhawaja/service_desk_portal/index.php" );

        exit;
    }
    else
    {


$_SESSION['rdr']="Invalid Login. Try Again.";


 header( "Location: https://noc.sde.site.com/okhawaja/Login/formLanding/login.php" );

        redirect(_WEBROOT_ . "/try1b.php");

        exit;
    }
    ldap_close($ds);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Anyone know how I can do a redirect on login screen upon submission?

Comment: You can't do that. Once you do the standard POST through the traditional form, your Jquery response will not be returned. You need to do the JQuery check first, then fire off the actual form in its success response. You can't fire off both at the same time like that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just post to script B via ajax, and use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the button from performing the standard form post?

Comment: im not 100% sure what the requirements are for scriptB to function properly but I have tried that many times and I get an empty error from scriptB when I try to post to it through AJAX.

Comment: you might be out of luck then. not sure if you can prevent the scriptB redirect when submitting it as a standard form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to stop the submit button for submitting the form, to do this add "return false;" at the end of the submit callback function like so:

```
error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        alert(status + ": " + err);
      }
    });

    return false;
  });

});
```

Then, in the success callback do whatever you need to, whether this is submit it on to the other URL or something else. This might work:

```
success: function(data, status, xhr){
    $('#form').unbind('submit');
    $('#form').submit();
},
```

Comment: the php code of scriptA does handling such as redirect on successful submission to www.examplesite2.com or on unsuccessful submission redirect back to login screen

Comment: I did what you said and now on submission I get redirected by scriptB's redirect..Why dont scriptA's redirect working?